# ESP 8266 reverse digitalWrite behaviour on which pins?

Tags: esp8266, pins, digitalwrite

I am using a device with an ESP 8266 microcontroller. I have discovered that setting `LED_BUILTIN` to `HIGH` turns the built-in LED **off** and  setting `LED_BUILTIN` to `LOW` turns the built-in LED **on**. This seems to be because the [microcontroller can sink more current than it can source](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-devkit-v1.0/issues/16).

Before I start using this microcontroller, I would like to know which other pins have this reverse behaviour. I've looked up datasheets for the ESP 8266 but I don't see how to discern this information. I would simply write a sketch to test, but I'm not sure what I might damage, and I'm not sure how to determine when an output pin is in the high-impedance state anyway.

**On the ESP 8266, how to know which pins are `HIGH -> 0v` and which pins are `HIGH -> 5v`?** Are the `HIGH -> 0v` pins necessarily `LOW -> 5v`? Where is this documented?

Comment: the pin is not reversed. the attached circuit with the LED reverses the signal.

Comment: @Juraj: Thank you. The pin is not reversed, but the behaviour (on this board and others) is. Are you saying that the issue is board-specific, so won't be relevant to all ESP 8266 boards? [This](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32822012864.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dxrV2yX) is the board that I'm using.

Comment: it is a Wemos D1 R1

Comment: the behaviour is not reversed ... a HIGH does not necessarily mean LED on ... a HIGH only means high output

Comment: Yes, or at lease a clone of one. I see mention on forums of people having this issue with [other ESP 8266 boards](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=399857.0) as well.

Comment: @jsotola: So if the output is HIGH, that would make the LED turn off only if the LED were pulled down to 0v on the same side as the pin, and connected to 5v on the other side (i.e. the pin is on the LED cathode). Is that how this board is wired? Where is that documented?

Comment: 'people' have issues with everything

Comment: @dotancohen, the schematic diagram is the documentation

Comment: @dotancohen, it is unclear what this means `LED were pulled down to 0v on the same side as the pin` .... how do you turn on a LED? ... one side is connected to HIGH and the other side is connected to ______

Comment: @dotancohen, you are overthinking this ... an LED lights up if there is a voltage difference across the LED, and that is all (assuming correct orientation) ... the LED will not light if both leads are grounded, or if both leads are conected to 5 V, or if both leads are connected to a 1000 V

Comment: @jsotola Where is that schematic diagram? I found the [WeMos D1 page on the Raspberry pie wiki](https://raspberrypiwiki.com/index.php/WEMOS_ESP8266_D1_R2_V2.1) but the diagram is [impossible to read](https://raspberrypiwiki.com/images/9/9b/WEMOS-ESP8266-D1-R2-V2.1-4.jpg). The Official WeMos site [doesn't seem to have such a diagram](https://www.wemos.cc/en/latest/d1/), mentioning only the D1 Mini.

Comment: I see on the [D1 Mini schematic](https://escapequotes.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/2020-02-10_12-06-36.jpg) that the LED is in fact connected with the cathode to the ESP 8266, but without the pulldown resistor that I suspected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The esp8266 must have a pull-up on io 2 for boot configuration. The Wemos D1 boards put the LED in series with the pull-up resistor on io 2. This creates the 'reversed' LED behavior.

[image]

The large D1s are retired and it is hard to find a good and readable schematics. The cut out is from D1 mini schematics.

Comment: I see now, thank you! I take it that this is common, but not necessary, on ESP 8266 boards.

Comment: I've found [the explanation of the boot configuration](https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?p=69022) and it is lucky that I did, as it is non-trivial and very important. Thank you Juraj!